# How to avoid implementing methods from abstract class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

For simplicity purposes, let's say I have a "Base" abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void BaseMethod(object obj);

    public abstract void BaseMethod();
}
```

I want to make a 2nd and 3rd class inherit from this "BaseClass":

```
public class Class1 : BaseClass
{
    public override void BaseMethod(object obj)
    {
        //Some code
    }
}

public class Class2 : BaseClass
{
    public override void BaseMethod()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Basically, **I want each of the classes to implementing one method without implementing the other**. The example above doesn't work, since for each class I'm prompted to implement the other abstract method.

**I'm aware I can just implement the other method 'empty'.** However, I'm trying to avoid this since I've found the following statement:

*Abstract classes can be inherited without implementing the abstract methods (though such a derived class is abstract itself)*

Is this statement wrong? Any input on this topic is deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: "***(though such a derived class is abstract itself)***" Trying to prevent a child class from implementing or overriding a particular base class method is an exercise in futility.  Simply go outside and beat your head against the sidewalk if you want to make yourself miserable.

Comment: Those classes would be fine if you make them `abstract`.  Of course any class that derives from them that isn't also `abstract` would have to implement the other method.  Maybe you could explain why you think you need to do this and we can suggest another approach. Maybe you really want two separate interfaces that each define those methods.

Comment: Much like Interfaces, abstract class may inherit other abstract classes. In that case, of course the derived class may not implement any abstract method of the base class. However, when you are inheriting from an abstract class, and your class is not abstract, you must implement all abstract methods. It's just like implementing an interface that is derived from another interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Abstract classes can be inherited without implementing the abstract methods (**though such a derived class is abstract itself**)

The bold part is the part you're not complying with - yes you can have an "intermediate" class that only implements some of the abstract methods, but *that class must be abstract as well*.   At some point, when you get to the concrete class, all abstract methods must be implemented; either in the class itself or somewhere up the inheritance chain.

Comment: you have a typo - you wrote much instead of must.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, I was struggling with that last part of the statement.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is not wrong, however to follow the statement your code needs to be changed to

```
public abstract class Class1 : BaseClass
{
    public override void BaseMethod(object obj)
    {
        //Some code
    }
}

public abstract class Class2 : BaseClass
{
    public override void BaseMethod()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

So you still will not be able to create the classes. A better solution would be make the functions virtual instead of abstract with a empty body or a body that throws a error.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void BaseMethod(object obj) { throw new NotImplmentedException(); }

    public abstract void BaseMethod() { throw new NotImplmentedException(); }
}
```

But I still think this is a bad idea, if you have a `List<BaseClass>` how will you know which is the correct version you will want to call? You should re-think your design to only have one virtual method that both functions can use.

Answer (score 1):

"Abstract classes can be inherited without implementing the abstract methods (though such a derived class is abstract itself)".

This statement is correct. It means that the classes 'Class1' and "Class2" would also have to be abstract if it is not implementing all the abstract methods.

Answer (score 1):

As said by others you can't. You have to divide your BaseClass in two different classes (if BaseClass is yours).

OR

you can "cheat" by wrapping or, as in the example, extending BaseClass in a certain way

```
    public class BaseClassWrapper : BaseClass
    {
        private IBaseMethodA methodA;

        private IBaseMethodB methodB;

        public BaseClassWrapper(IBaseMethodA methodA, IBaseMethodB methodB)
        {
            this.methodA = methodA;
            this.methodB = methodB;
        }

        public override void BaseMethod()
        {
            methodB.BaseMethod();
        }

        public override void BaseMethod(object obj)
        {
            methodA.BaseMethod(obj);
        }

        public interface IBaseMethodA
        {
            void BaseMethod(object obj);
        }

        public interface IBaseMethodB
        {
            void BaseMethod();
        }
    }
```

Now you have the two separate interface to implement.
This clearly make the design and implementation more complex but might give you some advantages. For example if you have 4 different implementation for IBaseMethodA and 3 for IBaseMethodB you can mix and match them.